# Spring w/ @EnableOAuth2Sso client tries to access /oauth/token via GET rather than POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a Spring Boot OAuth2 client & a Spring Boot OAuth 2 ResourceServer that's also an Authorization Service. I know what the problem is. I know OAuth 2 tokens are not allowed via get, only Post. However, I'm at a loss on how to fix it. This seems to come automatically w/ `@EnableOAuth2Sso` built in. In the code below you can see that class is bare bones. I haven't seen in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` mentioning a way to deal w/ this.

I'm not going to include the whole POM but I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE which includes spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE

I've included my classes & properties files w/ client-id & client-secret XXXed out, Client classes & props first:

Client application.properties:

```
server.port=7293
server.context-path=/ui
server.session.cookie.name=UISESSION

security.basic.enabled=false

security.oauth2.client.client-id=XXXXX
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=XXXXX
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://localhost:7291/auth/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=http://localhost:7291/auth/oauth/token
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:7291/auth/user/me

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Client Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class UISecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.antMatcher("/**")
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/", "/login**")
         .permitAll()
         .anyRequest()
         .authenticated();
   }    
}
```

Client Spring Boot app class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OAuth2ClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OAuth2ClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }   
}
```

Resource/Authentication Server App classes:

application.properties:

```
server.port=7291
server.context-path=/auth

security.oauth2.client.client-id=XXXXX
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=XXXXX

security.oauth2.authorization.checkTokenAccess=isAuthenticated()
security.oauth2.authorization.token-key-access=permitAll()

security.basic.enabled=false
```

Auth Server Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FilteringServiceAuthServerConfig.class);

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
          .withClient(clientId)
          .secret(clientSecret)
          .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
          .scopes("user_info")
          .autoApprove(true) ; 
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

and here's my Authorization Server Web Security Config class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.requestMatchers()
          .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/token")
          .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin().permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("XXXXX").password("XXXXX").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
}
```

and the Authorization / Resource Server combo Spring Boot Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class FilteringServiceApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FilteringServiceApp.class);

    @Value("${matches.file.name}")
    private String fileName;

    @Autowired 
    private FilterMatchRepository matchRepo;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        new MatchInitializer(matchRepo, fileName).init();
    }

    /**
     * Start up the Filter Matching Application
     * 
     * @param args 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FilteringServiceApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
        return new RequestContextListener();
    } 
}
```

the error i get when I access the URL this way (after authenticating via client_id & secret_id is:

{
    "error": "method_not_allowed",
    "error_description": "Request method 'GET' not supported"
}

i used NGrok to see what was happening as I got this error message & you can see that it's clearly accessing /oauth/token via a GET request which is against the spec. here's that output:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: http://localhost:7291/auth/oauth/token?client_id=XXXXX&redirect_uri=http://57bfa798.ngrok.io/ui/login&response_type=code&state=BgLGhq
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2018 09:42:30 GMT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed my AuthServerConfig class

```
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    //... other methods still the same. below fixed the error
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                 .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);
    }
}
```